# How do I replace more than 1 character in blackberry

Tags: java, regex, blackberry

I know how to replace a certain character with another character in a string:

> System.out.println(replaceAll("Where are you??", "?", ""))

```
public static String replaceAll(String front, String pattern, String back){

    if (front == null)
        return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); //A StringBuffer is created
    int idx = -1;
    int patIdx = 0;

    while ((idx = front.indexOf(pattern, patIdx)) != -1)
    {
        sb.append(front.substring(patIdx, idx));
        sb.append(back);
        patIdx = idx + pattern.length();
    }

    sb.append(front.substring(patIdx));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This code will replace all `?` with an empty space and would print out ("Where are you")

Now what I want to know is how can I replace more than 1 character. In Java I can just use simple regex, but if in blackberry I write something like:

`System.out.println(replaceAll("Henry!! Where are you??", "!?", ""))`

then blackberry doesn't pick it up. So how do I overcome this limitation that blackberry has?

Answer (score 4):

There is not any method to do it what you want. But i can suggest you that make an `array of string of the pattern which you want to replace`. Loop through the **array of string** get the string by their position and pass that in your

`public static String replaceAll(String front, String pattern, String back)`. Hope this will help you .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace any character in String  `front` that is used in String `pattern` you can use `toCharArray()`, iterate over all characters in pattern, check which is first to replace (which is nearest) and replace it. What I mean is something like this

```
public static String replaceAll(String front, String pattern, String back) {

    if (front == null)
        return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); // A StringBuffer is created
    int idx = -1;
    int patIdx = 0;


    boolean end = true;
    int tmp = -1;

    do {
        end = true;
        for (char c : pattern.toCharArray()) {
            //System.out.println("searching for->"+c+" from patIdx="+patIdx+" idx="+idx);
            if ((tmp = front.indexOf(c, patIdx)) != -1) {
                //System.out.println("FOUND->"+c+" from patIdx="+patIdx+" idx="+idx+" tmp="+tmp);
                if (idx == -1 || idx == patIdx-1 || (idx > patIdx && tmp < idx)){
                    end = false;
                    idx = tmp;
                    //System.out.println("setting replacement to ->"+c+" patIdx="+patIdx+" idx="+idx);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!end && idx != -1) {
            //System.out.println("replacing patIdx="+patIdx+" idx="+idx);
            sb.append(front.substring(patIdx, idx));
            sb.append(back);
            patIdx = idx+1;
        }
        //System.out.println("----");
    }while(!end);

    sb.append(front.substring(patIdx));
    return sb.toString();
}
```